# Where does Google Chrome get passwords from if chrome://settings/passwords is empty?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I was surprised to find that the `chrome://settings/passwords` is empty, with many sites not prompting for credentials and the credentials are definitely stored somewhere.

I have never logged into Google account in Chrome browser.

I also tried *Nirsoft ChromePass v1.55*, but it didn't find the credentials stored in Chrome.
However, I can still access various sites without entering credentials.

Anyone have any ideas how this is possible and where else can passwords be stored on the system?

Comment: Are you talking about that the password is prefilled in, or that you are automatically logged on? The last is a cookie, the first can be a password manager, but I too have found out on a computer with no extensions and no password stored in chrome, that it somehow still automatically remembers a password and fills this in, and I have been unable to find that password myself either, given that the password was changed, and I can now not find out where to remove/change the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sites not prompting you for credentials, then those sites may have cookies stored in chrome to remember who you are. You can find/delete them for each website here:

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```