# Chrome is saving passwords but not showing them in Settings

Tags: google-chrome, mac, passwords

Running Chrome 107.0.5304.110 on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro, macOS 12.6.1. Chrome asks to save passwords and fills them in properly, but when going to `chrome://settings/passwords` none of them appear.

It should be noted that my Chrome profile was made by copying the folder at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` from an old Mac, so it would carry over my history, plugins, and the like, from my old Mac. The only significant thing which didn't carry over were the passwords, which is understandable that it should be more secured and harder to transfer—I don't mind re-entering them. On the old Mac, it has all my passwords show up properly in Settings. But on the current Mac, even after putting in a password, it doesn't appear in Settings. It's clearly saved, just not in a way I can find and manage.

Also, I do not use my Google account to manage the passwords. Rather, they are set to always just be saved locally.

My guess is that had I set up Chrome from scratch, it would not have had this issue, but is there something specific that might be responsible for it which could be fixed, short of me starting Chrome over fresh?

Comment: Does [Where does Google Chrome get passwords from if chrome://settings/passwords is empty? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1674246/where-does-google-chrome-get-passwords-from-if-chrome-settings-passwords-is-em?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill No. It’s not that there is a cookie saving my logged-in status, but the passwords themselves are saved somewhere in Chrome. In the password field, it even has a button to take me to Chrome’s password manager, but when I click it, the list is unpopulated.